# Create a theme in Windows 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

In Windows 8, you were able to create your own themes for your application ([here's a tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263118.aspx)).

In Windows 8.1 Applications, themes are handled differently: you can change them at run-time and set a theme for a specific control in your XAML (if you don't want to apply the theme to the whole Application).

For instance:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" RequestedTheme="Dark">
```

However, I could not find a way to create my own themes. The property `RequestedTheme` takes an enumeration (its type is `FrameworkElement.RequestedTheme`) and an enumeration by definition cannot be extended (in C#). Also, if I want to define a new `Theme Dictionary` I would have written:

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

But it is not available in Windows 8.1.

How can one create a theme in Windows 8.1? Am I limited to the existing ones (light & dark)?

Comment: You don't create new themes, you override the 3 existing themes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you're restricted to 3 themes I believe

Default (light)
Dark
High Contrast

You can create new styles or override existing ones for the 3 themes like this in 8.1

```
 <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"/>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>               
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```